# regular expression to get date format after a particular string match

Tags: python, regex

I have to write a regular expression to extract date from this string in python
but date might get repeat so i only want to extract the date after **Invoice Value (in INR):**
i.e  **23/01/2023**
the string is

```
INVOICE DETAILS Invoice Number: Invoice Date: Invoice Value (in INR): 19 23/01/2023 2416.5 ITEM DETAILS CTSH:42029900 (ii) SKU NO : (iii)
```

This is working
`(?<=Invoice Value \(in INR\):\s\d\d\s)+\d{1,2}\/\d{1,2}\/\d{4}`

But it specifies the spaces and digits after the *Invoice Value (in INR):*
but these spaces and digits are not fixed
And I can't use \s* and \d*  inside the quantifier

Comment: Hey welcome to SO and thanks for including your code.  Can you tell us what Regex engine / programming language you are using?

Comment: Also, are you expecting that "INVOICE DETAILS..." will occur more than once in a row in the search text?  What is the point of the + in there?  As is, it is basically allowing the lookingbehind to occur more than once which is probably not needed.

Comment: This should work as well `(?<=Invoice Value \(in INR\):)[^\n\r]*?(\d{1,2}\/\d{1,2}\/\d{4})`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Surely there's something better, but this would work, using a capture group (named `my_date`):

`Invoice Value \(in INR\):\s*\d*\s*(?<my_date>\d{1,2}\/\d{1,2}\/\d{4})`

Take a look: https://regex101.com/r/GJxKb7/1